# Running long-lasting task by script. How to aviod error no 500?

Tags: php, cron

I have a script which imports products from CSV file to web shop. There are ~20.000 items to import so whole process may take 30-60 min. or more time. Script can by started manually by user using webbrowser or by CRON job. In both cases I want to use the same version of script. Import of new items (or updated current ones) will be done by every week.

My problem is server kills the script after ~5 min. of work

I set:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time' ,0);       
ini_set('set_memory_limit', -1)
```

I realized that I have to import only a bunch of items in a single run, for example 500 items. At the end of every run I'm going to save a status of import to database - for eg. items 0-500 were imported, so next time script should import 500-1000.

I'm not sure how should I do that. What I have to do after importing a bunch of items? Maybe I should do a redirect with status parameter in GET like:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/importer/import.php?package=4');
exit;
```

Is this a good way do achieve that? Will something like that work with cron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
session_start();

// This function should take care of importing
// If $limit is null it should import whole csv file
function importProcess($offset, $limit = null) {
    // some magic here
}

echo "Importing process in progress...";

// Script is called from command line
if (php_sapi_name() === 'cli') {
    importProcess(0, null);
} else {
    $num = 500;
    $offset = isset($_SESSION['offset']) ? (int) $_SESSION['offset'] : 0;

    if (importProcess($offset, $num)) {
        $_SESSION['offset'] = $offset+$num;
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/importer/import.php');
    } else {
        echo "Done";
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that when script is called by CRON there aren't problem with long-time running?

Comment: Yes, if you call script from CLI there should not be problems with long-time running.

Comment: It's stupid. I implemented this and I'm getting 504 timeout error.